# Integrating RTCMultiConnection with phone and mobile calls

Tags: webrtc, voip

I am using this library https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection to create web based  audio broadcasting application  like a radio but now my customer needs to take his phone and mobile calls audio stream and broadcast them along with his own audio stream 
So I wonder if there is any way to do that without depending  on other services
Any ideas would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Spangen in fact this is not an issue , I just don't know how to implement this task hence there are no prior trials for that